# Applescript: Error: -15266. The operation can’t be completed because some items had to be skipped

Tags: applescript

New to Applescript!

Syntax appears to be OK, but I'm getting the 15226 error. How do I resolve this?

When I run this script, I get the "Replies" (below):

```
set SourceFolder to POSIX file "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/"
set TargetFolder to POSIX file "/Volumes/RAID/BACKUP/"

tell application "Finder"
   activate
--  with timeout of 420 seconds
--  if exists TargetFolder then
--      try
--          delete TargetFolder
--      end try
--  end if
if exists SourceFolder then
    try
        duplicate SourceFolder to TargetFolder with replacing

    on error the error_message number the error_number
        display dialog "Error: " & the error_number & ". " & the error_message buttons {"OK"} default button 1
    end try

end if
--  end timeout

end tell
```

Replies:

```
tell application "Finder"
activate
exists file "Macintosh HD:Applications:MAMP:htdocs:"
    --> true
duplicate file "Macintosh HD:Applications:MAMP:htdocs:" to file "RAID:BACKUP:" with replacing
    --> current application
    --> error "The operation can’t be completed because some items had to be skipped. “htdocs”" number -15266
display dialog "Error: -15266. The operation can’t be completed because some items had to be skipped. “htdocs”" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
    --> {button returned:"OK"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss use the on error handler. you must decide your own error (elsewhere in the script) and call the error handler via "error number xxx"
here is the detail explanation with example from Apple site :[Apple developper error handler](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html)